# How do I install `libcurl` on centos stream 9 (or rocky 9)?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

I get the following error trying to install `libcurl` on a fresh CentOS stream 9 container:

```bash
$ docker run -it quay.io/centos/centos:stream9 /bin/bash
[root@72285314347a /]# yum install libcurl
CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS                                                                                                                                              1.8 MB/s | 6.2 MB     00:03
CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream                                                                                                                                           5.3 MB/s |  17 MB     00:03
CentOS Stream 9 - Extras packages                                                                                                                                      21 kB/s |  12 kB     00:00
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Tue May  9 18:24:40 2023.
Error:
 Problem: problem with installed package libcurl-minimal-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64
  - package libcurl-minimal-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64
  - package libcurl-minimal-7.76.1-19.el9.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64
  - package libcurl-minimal-7.76.1-20.el9.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64
  - package libcurl-minimal-7.76.1-21.el9.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64
  - package libcurl-minimal-7.76.1-22.el9.x86_64 conflicts with libcurl(x86-64) provided by libcurl-7.76.1-23.el9.x86_64
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I get the same error on Rocky 9 & 9.1.

Am I doing something wrong here? I can't believe these projects don't have an automated script that calculates package conflicts like this and raises sev-1 ship-blocking bugs.

Comment: Did you try the "try to add" suggestions?

Comment: package `dnf` requires `libcurl-minimal`. either it's a conflict or it's not. which is it?

Comment: @Songman Its easy for us to misinterpret what you are saying, but from what tou gave said you appear to be asking for help while holding the view you know better then everyone else (ie you dissed the project for not throwing up a warning not to ship and you dissed a reputed mod when he asked if you tried to follow the advice provided on how to fix the error.)

Comment: nobody's dissing anyone. not sure where you're getting that. my question is: is it a conflict or not?